# List of downstream consumers in Python

Tags: brightway

Is there a way to get the list of dowstream consumers of an activity in Python ? The downstream consumers appear on the Activity Browser so I guess there is a way to get them but I can't find it. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to do it, if you go the *naive* way you can loop through the the technosphere exchanges of all activities and see if the output of your activity appears there. Something like:

```
myact = mydb.random() # being mydb a brightway database

users = []
for activity in mydb:
    for exchange in activity.technosphere():
        if exchange.input == myact:
            users.append(activity)
```

This is probably not the fastest way to do it but it works. An alternative is to do the LCA of the activity. look into the row corresponding to the product of your activity, and see for which columns the value of that row is different from zero. I guess that is going to be faster.

Comment: Ok thank you, I was wondering if there was a direct way like for getting the exchanges or any attribute of the activity but it seems not.